# How a sling:resourceType will be working in cq:editconfig node property value which is self pointing?

Tags: aem, aem-6

In **AEM6.2**, I can see the `/libs/wcm/foundation/components/image` component `/libs/wcm/foundation/components/image/cq:editConfig/cq:dropTargets/image/parameters` node has a property `sling:resourceType` value `wcm/foundation/components/image` which is pointing to itself. **How this functionality behaviour works.?**

[image: foundation image]

Comment: [This tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/creating-cq-widget-supports-image.html) mentions the `sling:resourceType` as necessary to tell which component is supposed to render the content that gets dragged and dropped. Some experimentation shows that the properties of the `parameters` node somehow get merged with the properties of the component onto which we drag and drop an image. This seems to reset crops, among other things. Still, leaving the resource type empty in `properties` just causes the original resource type to be left intact.